# HTML, JS & CSS - How to set the position/display of the divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-position

I need help. I've made a first div(label:width) and 2nd div(input:width). They are inside of another div(control0). Same for div(control1, label:spacing, input:border).

What I want to achieve is place a label div next to the 2nd one. After clicking on the first one, the 2nd will move to the right and make a place for the range:input.

After clicking on the div again, the range:input with hide, and the 2nd div will be again close the 1st one.

I was trying to do it with flex, grid, inline-block etc. But there must be something messy with my code.

```js
var widthButton = document.getElementById('label_box_width');
var inputBoxWidth = document.getElementById('input_box_width');
var inputBoxWidth2 = document.getElementById('input_box_width2');
var borderButton = document.getElementById('label_box_width2');


var inputBoxBorder = document.getElementById('control0').lastElementChild;


function showWidthRange() {
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('widthAnimationToogleClass');
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('widthRange');
   
   
};
function showWidthRange2() {
   
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('widthAnimationToogleClass');
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('widthRange');
   
   
};
widthButton.addEventListener('click', showWidthRange);
borderButton.addEventListener('click', showWidthRange2);
```

```css
.divContainer {
  -webkit-filter:url('#goo');
  filter:url('#goo');
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:25px; 
}


#control0 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
/*  overflow: hidden;*/
/*  background-color: lightblue;*/
}
#control1 {
/*  overflow: hidden;*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
/*background-color: lightblue;*/
}
#label_box_width,
#label_box_width2 {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-animation: blop_label_box_width cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000) 3s  infinite;
    animation: blop_label_box_width cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000) 3s  infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blop_label_box_width {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
           -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: black;
    }
}
@keyframes blop_label_box_width {
   0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
   
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: black;
    }
}
#label_box_width:hover,
#label_box_width2:hover{
    background-color: darkorange;
}

#input_box_width,
#input_box_width2{
    margin: 13px 12px 12px 53.5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;  
}
.widthAnimationToogleClass {
    -webkit-animation:  blop_label_width cubic-bezier(0.570, 0.000, 0.275, 1.000) 2.5s  forwards;
    animation: blop_label_width  cubic-bezier(0.570, 0.000, 0.275, 1.000) 2.5s  forwards;
}
[class$="inputTest"]{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.widthRange {
    visibility: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blop_label_width {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
        width: 30px;
       -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 30px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
        transform: translateX(-30px);
    }
    75%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(360deg);
        transform: rotate3d(360deg);
    }
    90% {
        width:80px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
}
@keyframes blop_label_width {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         width: 30px;
       -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 30px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
        transform: translateX(-30px);
    }
    75%{
        opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    90% {
        width:80px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0px 2px 2px 8%;
  width: 80%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: url(im/space.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background: url(im/thesun.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -5.5px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: url(im/sky.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebTest</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="script.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>


<!-- INPUT DATA-->
<!--1st object-->
<div class="divContainer">
    <div id="control0" class="changeBox">
        <div id="label_box_width">
            width
        </div>
        <div id="input_box_width" class="widthRange">
            <input type="range"  name="width" min="50" max="500" value="100" data-sizing="px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--2nd object-->
    <div id="control1" class="changeBox">
      <div id="label_box_width2">
           spacing
      </div>
      <div id="input_box_width2" class="widthRange">
          <input type="range" name="spacing" min="0" max="20" value="10" data-sizing="px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SVG--------------------------------------------- -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -8" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```